# Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer not filling custom columns

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, serilog

I've looked around, but I could not find a working solution, and since all examples look alike I assume it must be me overlooking something obvious.
Also note this is my first real project using.NET Core and Serilog.

### The Problem

I am trying to log (using serilog) some custom properties into their own columns in the database as defined in `appsettings.json` and added via middleware on the pipeline. But the values remain NULL, even though the same items are correctly filled in the properties XML column.

So I have the expected new properties for authenticated users:

```
<properties>
    <property key="UserId">ff88ddb9-6f5a-4ad5-a2a8-1d016ff99398</property>
    <property key="UserName">ernst</property>
<properties>
```

But I want to also add these values to their own columns as well for some query optimizations.

### The code

The code is .NET Core 2.1+, and I've set up Serilog like shown at https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/samples/SimpleWebSample/Program.cs :

```
private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

public static int Main(string[] args)
{
  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
      .Enrich.FromLogContext()
      .MinimumLevel.Debug()
      .CreateLogger();
  try 
  {
    Log.Information($"Starting web host in {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"} environment, version {Util.Version.Long}");
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    return 0;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    return 1;
  }
  finally
  {
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
  }
}

 private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
                .UseSerilog()
                .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                .Build();
```

To add the information I use `LogContext.PushProperty` in my middleware.

The relevant pieces of the configuration:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Data Source=localhost;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False",
          "tableName": "SeriLog_Custom",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "customColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "UserId",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "DataLength": 450,
                "AllowNull": true
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "UserName",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "DataLength": 256,
                "AllowNull": true

              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Furthermore, besides not filling the custom columns, the database is also created in the standard way without these column, so I added them by hand.

This could point to a configuration issue?

The SQL to create the table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SeriLog_Custom](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MessageTemplate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Level] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Properties] [xml] NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SeriLog_Custom] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now I can get the desired info with:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Message]
      ,[MessageTemplate]
      ,[Level]
      ,[TimeStamp]
      ,[Exception]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[Properties].value('(//property[@key="UserName"]/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName
      ,[Properties]
  FROM [ECSControl].[dbo].[SeriLog_ECMonitor]
  where [Properties].value('(//property[@key="UserName"]/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'ernst'
  order by id desc;
```

But I want to access it with:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Message]
      ,[MessageTemplate]
      ,[Level]
      ,[TimeStamp]
      ,[Exception]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[Properties]
  FROM [ECSControl].[dbo].[SeriLog_ECMonitor]
  where  UserName = 'ernst'
  order by id desc;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest stable version of `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer (5.1.2)` doesn't have `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` support. The same with the latest stable version of  `Serilog.Settings.Configuration (2.6.1)` ([ref](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#serilog-configuration-package-net-standard--net-core)).

Updating to pre-release versions `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.1.3-dev-00204` and `Serilog.Settings.Configuration 3.0.0-dev-00119` solves this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

I tried  the dev build, but that threw exceptions, so I resorted to hardcode the sink instead and now it works.

Comment: Any update on this ? Does `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer` have `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` support now ?

Comment: Thank you. This saved my day, I tried the latest releases and I dont think its fixed yet.

Comment: @Ernst Do you have an example of how you hard-coded the sink?

Comment: @Ernst Do you have an example of how you hardcoded the sink to populate the new column?