# Writing custom columns to MS SQL Server with Serilog sink

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, serilog

I am trying to use Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer sink to write custom columns to log table.  Per [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver), I've added a `columnOptionsSection`:

```
"columnOptionsSection": {
  "additionalColumns": [
    {
      "ColumnName": "MachineName",
      "DataType": "nvarchar",
      "DataLength": 100
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have `"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]` further down (and it works fine with `File` sink).

The log is written but `MachineName` column is NULL.  @AlexRiabov [states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062133/9382) that the current version of the sink doesn't have doesn't have `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` support.  This is contradicted by the documentation which has an entire section devoted to it.  He also states that updating to the latest dev version resolves the issue - however, that version throws exceptions so I can't use it.

So my questions...

1. Is it possible to define custom columns to use with the MSSqlServer sink from appsettings.json?  If so, how?
2. Is `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer` sink still being worked on?  Last major release appears to have been over a year ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5.1.3-dev-00236 worked for me

make sure you have the Environment enrichers library added

my appSettings json:

```
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [{
            "Name": "MSSqlServer",
            "Args": {
                "connectionString": --removed--,
                "schemaName": "dbo",
                "tableName": "Logs",
                "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
                "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
                "batchPostingLimit": 5,
                "period": "0.00:00:02",
                "columnOptionsSection": {
                    "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
                    "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties" ],
                    "additionalColumns": [
                        {
                            "ColumnName": "UtcTimeStamp",
                            "DataType": "datetimeoffset",
                            "AllowNull": false
                        },
                        {
                            "ColumnName": "MachineName",
                            "DataType": "nvarchar",
                            "DataLength": 128,
                            "AllowNull": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }]
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been using it in prod for several months now and it's pretty solid.  One change I would make in your file is increase the batchPostingLimit.  You don't want your app to be constantly writing logs.  I set mine at 1000 records or every 5 seconds.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind - i've got it set really low for development purposes - thanks